# Push notification on iphone applications

Tags: ios4

I want to send advertisements to the application users using Push notification but i don't know is it possible or not.Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send advertisements to your users, I would suggest **`iAd`**, theres a nifty tool called [iAd Producer](http://developer.apple.com/iad/iadproducer/).

Another way to deliver other content besides iAds would be to use a `UIWebView` and create your own web based content that you can present as a modal view, or however else you would like.

Comment: If we use iAd, we are writing the code in the application itself right?But my requirement is to send ads to the applications who all downloaded it from appstore as online.

Comment: You will need to use iAd then. Read more on the iAd Framework: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html

Comment: Can you tell me iAds works as online,is the content of the ad can change according to us?How frequently these ads are coming up?

Comment: Yes, you would have to read more on the iAd Framework to see how to target specific audiences / ads, etc.